# Pass parameters to docker-compose command

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

ARG CMD_ARGS=$CMD_ARGS
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
```

And Docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    ports:
    - 4444:4444
    restart: always

  app:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
    - .:/app
    command: sh -c "python3 my_script.py -arg1 -arg2"
    depends_on:
      - selenium
```

Is there a way not to hardcode arg1,arg2 in docker-compose.yml file and instead pass it in docker-compore up command OR using environmental variables (args containing whitespace characters) somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `Variable substitution` for your case.

example from docs:

```
db:
  image: "postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION}"
```

> When you run docker-compose up with this configuration, Compose looks
> for the POSTGRES_VERSION environment variable in the shell and
> substitutes its value in. For this example, Compose resolves the image
> to postgres:9.3 before running the configuration.
>
> If an environment variable is not set, Compose substitutes with an
> empty string. In the example above, if POSTGRES_VERSION is not set,
> the value for the image option is postgres:.

or for passing variable to `command` You can use `$$`.

> You can use a $$ (double-dollar sign) when your configuration needs a
> literal dollar sign. This also prevents Compose from interpolating a
> value, so a $$ allows you to refer to environment variables that you
> don’t want processed by Compose.

example:

```
app:
  command: sh -c "python3 my_script.py $$VAR_ARG_1"
```

and on cli, You need to set `VAR_ARG_1` variable.